# Split and Convert string to List<T>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, string, split

I'm trying to convert a string to different objects. I'm using a generic method to do that.

```
        public T TryParseStruct<T>(string strObject)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strObject) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strObject))
            return default(T);
        try
        {
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            return (T)converter.ConvertFromString(strObject);
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException ex)
        {
            return default(T);
        }
    }
```

Everything works great when I pass obiects as long, bool etc.

```
TryParseStruct<Int64>(strObject); 
TryParseStruct<Boolean>(strObject);
```

The problem is that the method fails when I pass generic lists in to it, for example:

```
TryParseStruct<List<Int64>>(strObject); 
TryParseStruct<List<Int32>>(strObject);
```

Can any one help me to do that (splitting the string in ',' and convert it to the list given)??

Comment: string[] arrayStr = input.Split(new char[] {','}).ToArray();

Comment: I think you should use IEnumrabe instead List

Comment: Type your string here, we have to know your string format clearly.

Comment: `TrtParseStruct` is not a standard library method, so you need to show us its body if we are to reason about it. However the name `TryParseStruct` implies that it works with value types and `List<T>` is a reference type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my pinion, I will use IEnumerable return type to make a function for myself:
Try this [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cnnNQT)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

public class Program
{
    private static string yourString = "12,45,32,34,56,65,44,56,24,43453,3424,3436345,342342,453424,2342,664,43542,234,2346346,6,234,5566";
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Using IEnumerable");
        foreach (int item in GetEnumerableIntFromString(yourString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Using List");
        foreach (int item in GetListIntFromString(yourString))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    // Using IEnumerable
    private static IEnumerable<int> GetEnumerableIntFromString(string str)
    {
        string[] splitString = str.Split(new[]{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach(string item in splitString)
        {
            yield return Convert.ToInt32(item);
        }
    }

    // Using List
    private static List<int> GetListIntFromString(string str)
    {
        List<int> yourList = new List<int>();
        string[] splitString = str.Split(new[]{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach(string item in splitString)
        {
            yourList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(item));
        }
        return yourList;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Using IEnumerable
12
45
32
34
56
65
44
56
24
43453
3424
3436345
342342
453424
2342
664
43542
234
2346346
6
234
5566
Using List
12
45
32
34
56
65
44
56
24
43453
3424
3436345
342342
453424
2342
664
43542
234
2346346
6
234
5566
```

More information: If you have an `Enumerable` want to **Convert to `List`**:

```
Enumerable<int> enumerable = yourEnumerable;
List<int> asList = enumerable.ToList();
```